# Regex match literal string

Tags: regular-expressions

I want to write a function (or use an existing one) that will take any string and produce a correctly escaped Regex that matches only that string. What is the fastest and simplest way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for [`regexp-quote`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Functions.html#Regexp-Functions):

> This function returns a regular expression whose only exact match is string. Using this regular expression in looking-at will succeed only if the next characters in the buffer are string; using it in a search function will succeed if the text being searched contains string.
>
> This allows you to request an exact string match or search when calling a function that wants a regular expression.

Comment: I swear, I searched the docs and Google, I just didn't think of _quote_ as a keyword. Thanks.

Comment: `regexp-quote` has the nice alternate use of escaping special characters in a string properly for use when a function expects a regexp in "Emacs form"--e.g. if you can't remember how many backslashes to use to escape a literal backslash, just run it through `regexp-quote` in the `scratch` buffer or `ielm`.